# Can i make code that will rotate my image every 10 seconds?

Tags: html, image, rotation

Can i make code that will rotate my image every 10 seconds using any language.
Here is code i'am using:

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:lightgreen;
border:4px solid gray;
border-radius:100px;
}
```

Comment: How u know it dude? Yep, i got it for homework yesterday ...

Comment: If it is homework, you should find out your self. do not expect us to do it for you. Look up CSS @keyframes if you want to do it in CSS.

Comment: This platform is not for solving home works. Look up for jquery http://www.w3schools.com/jQuery/

Comment: GUys, of course it's not for homework -.-

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can :)
Add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
```

And then try this:

```
var x=$(".circle");
var angle = 15;
setInterval(function(){
    x.rotate(angle);
},10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

Add Jquery plugin.

```
    var angle = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
     var interval_rotate = setInterval(function(){
        angle++;
    $('.circle').css('transform','rotate('+angle+'deg)');
    $('.circle').css('-ms-transform','rotate('+angle+'deg)');
    $('.circle').css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle+'deg)');


}, 10000);
})
```

;